# How to run inline script in Vagrant?

Tags: vagrant

I am new to Vagrant and am trying to execute an inline script as documented. My understanding is that when I `vagrant ssh`, I should see the output of inline execution.  But I don't see it.  Tried again after `vagrant reload` but no luck. Is there anything wrong here? `Vagrant version 1.7.2`

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  ...
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "echo I am Ubuntu"
end
```

Another variation I tried and failed was

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  ...
  config.vm.provision "shell" do |s|
    s.inline: "echo I am Ubuntu"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run

```
vagrant provision
```

in order to see the message.

[Provisioning](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/provisioning.html) is meant to run just once when you launch a new vm for the first time and it will run actions to setup the machine.